# Connecting to MYSQLi through Terminal in Mac OS using MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mysqli, mamp

I am trying to run my PHP script via Terminal in Mac. When I try to run the script, I am getting this error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

This is how I am trying to connect:

mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','my_db');

I also tried to connect using the host: 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and I then got this error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

From what I've read online it might have something to do with mysql socket, but whatever I try to do to get this to work doesn't help.

I even tried to connect using the following as my host:

:/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

:/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Any idea what can be the problem/solution?

Comment: Is MySQL actually running on your computer?

Comment: Yes, it runs good on my browser with no errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue. Here's what I did.

1. Open Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/terminal.app)
2. Use your favorite text editor to create/edit `~/.bash_profile`. For instance, if you're using vim, type `vim ~/.bash_profile`. I use TextMate, so I typed `mate ~/.bash_profile`.
3. Add these lines:

   ```
   export MAMP_SQL=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin 
   export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin
   export PATH="$MAMP_SQL:$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
   ```

   These lines ensure that the first versions of MySQL and PHP that are found (and therefore used) are the versions used by MAMP. **NB:** Make sure that php5.5.10 matches the version MAMP is using. You can check this against `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/index.php?page=phpinfo&language=English` by default. ***SAVE THE FILE*** (I shouldn't have to save this, but invariably someone complains that it doesn't work).
4. Close your terminal window and reopen. This restarts the shell, which will load your `.bash_profile` script.
5. Type `which php`. You should get something akin to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php`
6. Type `which mysql`. You should get something akin to `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql`

If for any reason you get something different than the responses from 5 and 6, go back and check your .bash_profile; chances are you just neglected to save it properly.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, I really appreciate your help you gave me the best and only answer to this problem!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL installed on your computer, you can do the following command:

```
mysql -u "username"
```

replacing "username" with the username of your computer

NOTE: often times root does not work, try the username of your computer

Comment: Yes this does work but its not the problem I am having. I am trying to make a connection through the PHP script itself. I basically want to run the my script via terminal.

Comment: maybe try running sudo php yourfile.php

Comment: It should not be a permission error since it actually tries to run the script and the only error it is facing is connecting to mysql. Anyways, I have tried it with sudo and so far same error...

Comment: maybe its a simple error then?  go to phpmyadmin and make sure your username and password are what you typed them as

Comment: I know for a fact that I dont have any problem with my username, password, or database info. I am able to run the script just fine with no connection error if I run it through my browser. The problem only appears when using terminal.